# Table is not wide enough, caption is at wrong location, and the top line missed

Tags: tables, width

I want a table like this
[image]

ignore the content please, what I have is this, can anybody help me? Thanks

```
\begin{table}[!ht]  
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{cccc}
    %\toprule
           & Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \midrule
    Group1 & 0.8   & 0.1   & 0.1  \\
    Group2 & 0.1   & 0.8   & 0.1  \\
    Group3 & 0.1   & 0.1   & 0.8  \\
    Group4 & 0.34  & 0.33  & 0.33 \\ \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Vertical and lateral stresses of mortar.}
  \label{c}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! If your real table has code as you show in  question, than this can lead to an ugly, difficult to read table (depend on used page layout). But this up to you. Your table can have such form by use `tabularx` (as is suggested in @WinnieNotThePooh answer) or by `tabular*` or by new package `tabularray`.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in my comment, it seems that you tand to have typographically looking, an ugle table. Well, this judgement is based on lack of information about your document layout and is very opinion based.

Let assume, that your document has two columns. Beside use od `tabularx` for it you have two more possibilities to write it:

- by use of `tabular*`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Vertical and lateral stresses of mortar.}
\label{c}
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}}  lll }
    \toprule
           & Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ 
    \midrule
Group1 & 0.8   & 0.1   & 0.1  \\
Group2 & 0.1   & 0.8   & 0.1  \\
Group3 & 0.1   & 0.1   & 0.8  \\
Group4 & 0.34  & 0.33  & 0.33 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

- by use of `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Vertical and lateral stresses of mortar.}
\label{c}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={l *{3}{X[l]} },
                 rowsep =0pt}}
    \toprule
           & Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ 
    \midrule
Group1 & 0.8   & 0.1   & 0.1  \\
Group2 & 0.1   & 0.8   & 0.1  \\
Group3 & 0.1   & 0.1   & 0.8  \\
Group4 & 0.34  & 0.33  & 0.33 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Which result is similar as is at previous example.

[image]

**Edit:**
In the case that caption had to be as is shown on picture in your question, than you need to document preamble of examples add:

```
\usepackage[skip=1ex,
            font=small, labelfont=bf, 
            labelsep=newline, singlelinecheck=false
            ]{caption}
```

Result will become:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The top rule is missing because you commented the line with `\toprule`.

I'd not enlarge tables to the text width, unless they're already almost as wide.

In the first example below, you see that the big white space hinders reading with no advantage for the clarity of the table.

In the second example, the spaces are made a bit wider than the default.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\begin{document}

\lipsum[10][1-5]

\begin{table}[!htp]

\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  @{}
}
\toprule
& {Item1} & {Item2} & {Item3} \\
\midrule
Group1 & 0.8  & 0.1  & 0.1  \\
Group2 & 0.1  & 0.8  & 0.1  \\
Group3 & 0.1  & 0.1  & 0.8  \\
Group4 & 0.34 & 0.33 & 0.33 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\caption{Vertical and lateral stresses of mortar.}
\label{c}

\end{table}

\lipsum[20][1-5]

\begin{table}[!htp]
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2\tabcolsep}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  @{}
}
\toprule
& {Item1} & {Item2} & {Item3} \\
\midrule
Group1 & 0.8  & 0.1  & 0.1  \\
Group2 & 0.1  & 0.8  & 0.1  \\
Group3 & 0.1  & 0.1  & 0.8  \\
Group4 & 0.34 & 0.33 & 0.33 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Vertical and lateral stresses of mortar.}
\label{c1}

\end{table}

\lipsum[40][1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I recommend using `S` columns from `siunitx` for tables with numeric data.

If you want the caption at the top, then put it there. Better loading `caption`, in this case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\begin{document}

\lipsum[10][1-5]

\begin{table}[!htp]

\caption{Vertical and lateral stresses of mortar.}
\label{c}

\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  @{}
}
\toprule
& {Item1} & {Item2} & {Item3} \\
\midrule
Group1 & 0.8  & 0.1  & 0.1  \\
Group2 & 0.1  & 0.8  & 0.1  \\
Group3 & 0.1  & 0.1  & 0.8  \\
Group4 & 0.34 & 0.33 & 0.33 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}

\lipsum[20][1-5]

\begin{table}[!htp]
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2\tabcolsep}

\caption{Vertical and lateral stresses of mortar.}
\label{c1}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  @{}
}
\toprule
& {Item1} & {Item2} & {Item3} \\
\midrule
Group1 & 0.8  & 0.1  & 0.1  \\
Group2 & 0.1  & 0.8  & 0.1  \\
Group3 & 0.1  & 0.1  & 0.8  \\
Group4 & 0.34 & 0.33 & 0.33 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\lipsum[40][1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/AnMnv/eBook (example 4.12)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,
top=1.5cm,bottom=2cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
     
            
\begin{table}[!ht] 
\caption{Vertical and lateral stresses of mortar.}  
\vspace{0.5cm}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X  X  X  X}
           & Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \midrule
    Group1 & 0.8   & 0.1   & 0.1  \\
    Group2 & 0.1   & 0.8   & 0.1  \\
    Group3 & 0.1   & 0.1   & 0.8  \\
    Group4 & 0.34  & 0.33  & 0.33 \\ \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\label{c}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]